# mongodb How to install PHP Driver in lampp (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to install mongoDB on ubuntu by using the following command

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install mongo
```

But the next error appeared

```
WARNING: "pecl/mongo" is deprecated in favor of "channel:///mongodb" WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update pecl/mongo requires PHP (version >= 5.3.0, version <= 5.99.99), installed version is 7.1.6 No valid packages found install failed
```

then i changed the command to:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install mongodb
```

but the following error

```
Package "mongodb" Version "1.4.4" does not have REST xml available install failed
```

please help me

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt install php-mongodb`? (_Note:_ Do not install `php-mongo`, since that's the old and deprecated driver)

Comment: Thank you for replying, I used the code you sent and the installation was done, and i add extension=mongodb.so  in php.ini file, after that I restart the server but Mongo details are not showing in phpinfo()

Comment: If you have a standard install of Ubuntu, you don't need to enable the extensions manually in your php.ini. It should already be enabled. Also, if you do, make sure that you're editing the correct ini-file. (There are different files for CLI, Apache and php-fpm). Do you have multiple php-versions installed? You seem to be using PHP7.1 while Ubuntu 16.04 comes with 7.0 and Ubuntu 18.04 comes with 7.2. Also, are you using Apache with mod_php or Nginx with php-fpm? If you're using php-fpm, you need to restart that service as well.

Comment: ...btw, in Ubuntu, you usually don't need to edit php.ini at all. It has all the available extensions in: `/etc/php/7.1/mods-available/20-mongodb.ini`. Then you enable them by symlinking them in (for Apache): `/etc/php/7.1/apache/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini`. However, this is usually done for you when you install an extension.

Comment: I have added extension=mongodb.so line to my php ini by using the next command  echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||" . But mongodb is  listed in the available modules list when I run php -m and  There is  PHP Warning:  Module 'mongodb' already loaded in Unknown on line 0, What do you advise me to solve this problem

Comment: I removed extension=mongodb.so line from my php ini and mongodb is listed in the available modules list when I run php -m and There is no startup warning / error but   Mongo details are not showing in phpinfo()

Comment: `php -m` is for cli while I'm guessing `phpinfo()` is displayed through a browser? As mentioned, make sure that you got a symlink to the mongodb.ini file in your `/etc/php/7.1/apache/conf.d/` (if you're running Apache, that is). Every environment (cli, Apache, php-fpm) has their own configs so you can have different extensions enabled in cli and in Apache. Also make sure that `phpinfo()` and `php -v` shows the same PHP versions, so you're not also editing the wrong version. (Every version also has their own configs).

Comment: `phpinfo() ( Version 7.1.6 ) ` and  `php -v  ( Version 7.2.5 )`  shows  the different PHP versions and i found mongodb.ini file in `/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/`, did i install mongodb in the wrong way

Comment: @magnus-eriksson please advice me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

As the error message stated, the first extension you tried to install, mongo, is deprecated. The extension you want is mongodb.

Rather than use a package manager, I would recommend installing it manually. That way you customize its options, such as SSL support, which you may need for certain authentication methods. Per the [installation manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.manual.php), the steps are as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver.git
cd mongo-php-driver
git submodule update --init
phpize
./configure [options]
make all
sudo make install
```

Comment: I tried to install mongo by the command that you sent, but the following error appears when i tried  to run the  command  `./configure [options]`  `configure:WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target configure: WARNING:invalid host type: [options] checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep configure: error: /bin/bash ./config.sub [options] failed`